# Remove first two characters in column using sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a dataset like below:

```
df
      ColA     ColB
-_jdn-endm        6
-_mek-emdn        5
```

Expected Output

```
      ColA     ColB     New_col
-_jdn-endm        6    jdn-endm
-_mek-emdn        5    mek-emdn
```

I want to remove the first two characters from ColA.

I tried this an I got a syntax error even though it looks correct:

```
library(sqldf)
df<- sqldf("SELECT RIGHT([ColA], LEN(ColA]) - 2) [New_col] FROM df")

Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you need to escape parentheses? Try `\\(`, `\\)`.

Comment: And you need to do this in `sqldf`, you can't just use `substr`?

Comment: yeah it needs to be sqldf unfortunately. I know how to it using R syntax already.

Comment: no luck with removing the parenthesis either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr` extracting character 3 onwards.

```
sqldf("select *, substr(Col_A, 3) as newCol from df")
```